# Android ProgressDialog issue

Tags: android

My Login page has a progress dialog while querying the database and if the user enter a wrong username or password the progress bar is not dismissed and i can't do anything beside closing the app.

This the code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    final UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    inputUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    final String prefUtilizador = preferences.getString("username", "Default NickName");
    final String prefPassword = preferences.getString("password", "Default Password");
    boolean logged_in = preferences.getBoolean("checkBox", false);
    if (prefUtilizador.equals("") && prefPassword.equals("") ||!logged_in) {
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("onClick", "Login");
                new GetLogin().execute();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.d("Username", prefUtilizador);
        Log.d("Boolean", String.valueOf(true));
        //Dados no login
        inputUser.setText(prefUtilizador);
        inputPassword.setText(prefPassword);
        JSONObject prefJson = userFunction.loginUser(prefUtilizador, prefPassword);
        try {
            Log.d("Sucesso", KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (prefJson.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                String res = prefJson.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    Log.d("Valor", res);
                    JSONObject json_user = prefJson.getJSONObject("user");
                    String idUser = json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL);
                    Intent entrada = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    entrada.putExtra("idUser", idUser);
                    Log.d("idUser", idUser);
                    startActivity(entrada);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private class GetLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("A validar o login..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        inputUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        String utilizador = inputUser.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(utilizador, password);
        try {
            Log.d("Sucesso", KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                //loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    Log.d("Valor", res);
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    String nome = json_user.getString(KEY_NOME);
                    String user = json_user.getString(KEY_UTIL);
                    String idUser = json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL);
                    String tipo = json_user.getString(KEY_TIPO);
                    Log.d("Nome", nome);
                    Log.d("user", user);
                    Log.d("idUser", idUser);
                    Log.d("tipo", tipo);
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NOME), json_user.getString(KEY_UTIL), json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL));
                    //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
                    if (Integer.parseInt(tipo) == 2) {
                        Intent entrada = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        entrada.putExtra("idUser", json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL));
                        entrada.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(entrada);
                        fechaProgressBar();
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Error in login
                    loginErrorMsg
                            .setText("Dados utilizador/password errados");
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void fechaProgressBar() {
        if (pDialog != null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

UPDATE

```
private class GetLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("A validar o login..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        inputUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        String utilizador = inputUser.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(utilizador, password);
        try {
            Log.d("Sucesso", KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                //loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    Log.d("Valor", res);
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    String nome = json_user.getString(KEY_NOME);
                    String user = json_user.getString(KEY_UTIL);
                    String idUser = json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL);
                    String tipo = json_user.getString(KEY_TIPO);
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NOME), json_user.getString(KEY_UTIL), json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL));
                    //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
                    if (Integer.parseInt(tipo) == 2) {
                        Intent entrada = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        entrada.putExtra("idUser", json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL));
                        entrada.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(entrada);
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Error in login
                    loginErrorMsg
                            .setText("Dados utilizador/password errados");

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void fechaProgressBar() {
        if (pDialog != null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute();
        Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pDialog.hide();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Error: Method onPostExecute is never used**

UPDATE 2

```
 private class GetLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("A validar o login..");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        inputUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        String utilizador = inputUser.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(utilizador, password);
        try {
            Log.d("Sucesso", KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                //loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    Log.d("Valor", res);
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    String nome = json_user.getString(KEY_NOME);
                    String user = json_user.getString(KEY_UTIL);
                    String idUser = json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL);
                    String tipo = json_user.getString(KEY_TIPO);
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NOME), json_user.getString(KEY_UTIL), json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL));
                    //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
                    if (Integer.parseInt(tipo) == 2) {
                        Intent entrada = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        entrada.putExtra("idUser", json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL));
                        entrada.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(entrada);
                        finish();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Error in login
                    loginErrorMsg
                            .setText("Dados utilizador/password errados");

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void fechaProgressBar() {
        if (pDialog != null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        super.onPostExecute(v);
        Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });

    }
}}
```

The progressBar doesn't dismiss...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to manipulate the UI from the `doInBackground` method. Move the call of `fetchAProgressBar()` method to `onPostExecute`.

UI should be manipulated only from the main thread. Handle all processing inside  doInBackground. Manipulate UI from onPostExecute. onPostExecute, onPreExecute, onProgressUpdate is called on the main thread. doInBackground is called in a seperate thread within Asynctask's thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't update UI works in doInBackGround method**

```
loginErrorMsg
                            .setText("Dados utilizador/password errados");
```

This is wrong. You can not update UI in `doInBackground` method. Move this to `onPostExecute`

Also you don't need this in `doINBAckground` move thin to `onPreExecute`)_

```
inputUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
```

**Edit 1:**

Also move this `fechaProgressBar();` outside of `try/catch` block or move to `onPostExecute` method.

Answer (score 0):

add onPostExecute in your AsyncTask 
    `@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }`

Comment: change your Asynctask from 
private class GetLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
to 
private class GetLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>

Comment: Now i have errror : onPostExecute (String) in AsyncTask cannot be applied to 0

Comment: try changing  `private class private class GetLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>` to` GetLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` and `protected void onPostExecute(String result`) to
`protected void onPostExecute(Void v)`. this should fix

Comment: Made your suggested changes and still have error " An error occured while executing doInBackground()" check new update

Answer (score 0):

you are manipulating background thread from UI thread that's why app crashes 
use post executer with inside that method

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute();
           ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
           pDialog.hide();

            }
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        inputUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginUser);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        String utilizador = inputUser.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(utilizador, password);
        try {
            Log.d("Sucesso", KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                //loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    Log.d("Valor", res);
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                    String tipo = json_user.getString(KEY_TIPO);
                    userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NOME), json_user.getString(KEY_UTIL), json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL));
                    //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
                    if (Integer.parseInt(tipo) == 2) {
                        Intent entrada = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        entrada.putExtra("idUser", json_user.getString(KEY_IDUTIL));
                        entrada.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(entrada);
                        fechaProgressBar();
                        finish();
                        return true;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Error in login
                    return false;

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void fechaProgressBar() {
        if (pDialog != null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean v) {
        super.onPostExecute(v);
        if(v==false){
            loginErrorMsg.setText("username/password errados");
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    }
```